# how to solve issue for playing mp4 file using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I get the following error while running the command:

```
ffprobe.exe -f h264 AndrewFlintoff_Cricket.mp4
```

> error: "Diverting av_*_packet function calls to libavcodec. Recompile to improve performance"

Comment: How to solve this error?

Comment: Does ffprobe just exit after this? What result are you expecting? Are you sure the codec is h.264? What happens if you omit `-f h264`? What does ffmpeg -i AndrewFlintoff_Cricket.mp4 show? There is not enough information in the question.